# Existence of analytic function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Is there an analytic function in a disc around the origin such that $f^3(z)=z^2$ for all $z$ in that circle?
I would like a hint.

Comment: Your function $f$ satisfies $f(0)=0$, so it has the form $zg(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ (in a neighbourhood of $0$). Now, look at $f(z)^3/z^2$ as $z\to 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have seen a proof that there is no continuous determination of the logarithm on any circle around $0$, try to imitate it.

Comment: @Etienne $z=0$ isn't necessarily a member of the domain, as I read the question (although OP's acceptance of mrf's answer appears contradictory to that).

Comment: it seems that in the question, "circle" has been replaced by "disc"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $f(0)=0$. Differentiate your equation a few times, plug in $z=0$ and see what you can conclude.

Comment: It seems to me the original problem assumed analyticity on a *circle*, rather than a disc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the domain and image of your function. I'll assume $\mathbb{C}$ for both.

If you integrate both side twice. you'll end up with a polynomial who's holomorphic and whose third derivative is, almost trivially, $z^2$.

Comment: I don't think the OP means $f'''$ but rather $(f)^3$.